# How can I keep firefox zoom stable on mac?

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm a longtime linux user who just got a Macbook. I am using Firefox, and every time I Cmd + to zoom in on a web page, the change isn't stable. If I move to another tab then back, the zoom has reverted to the default. This is really frustrating because I have to manually zoom every time I change tabs.

How can I keep the zoom level stable?

Comment: I'd say that's a Firefox issue specifically. If I do the same in Safari, not only is it remembered for that specific tab, it's also remembered for that specific page on that specific site, even through relaunches.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's strange because Firefox doesn't have this behavior on my linux or windows machines. The zoom works as expected on them.

Comment: @Tetsujin Huh you're right though, Safari works as expected on my machine.

Comment: I'd file it as a bug. I don't use FF myself, just tested what I expected Safari to do… & it did.

Comment: Oddly enough (and just as a data point) it doesn't do that on my Mac (latest OS and latest Firefox). In fact it even retains zoom level if I quit and re-open Firefox. Strange indeed.